# SQL Count in Hibernate HQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Is it possible to build following SQL statement in Hibernate HQL?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

Comment: Just google "select count hql" :)

Comment: @SavinoSguera now googling this drive here, because of you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a hibernate setup available to test, but it seems like you can:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation

Answer (score 13):

Of course it is:

```
select count(e) from Entity e;
```

Such answers are very easily findable in the [reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-aggregation).

Answer (score 4):

Using Aggregate Functions

```
Query q = session
            .createQuery("select count(*), max(eb.Eid) , min(eb.Eid) , sum(eb.Eid) , avg(eb.Eid) from Employee eb");

    List l = q.list();

    // Object result[]= (Object[])l.get(0);
    // for(Object i:result){
    // System.out.println(result[(int)i]);
    // }

    Object result[] = (Object[]) l.get(0);

    Long res1 = (Long) result[0];
    long count = res1.longValue();

    Integer res2 = (Integer) result[1];
    long max = res2.longValue();

    Integer res3 = (Integer) result[2];
    long min = res3.longValue();

    Long res4 = (Long) result[3];
    long sum = res4.longValue();

    Double res5 = (Double) result[4];
    double avg = res4.doubleValue();

    System.out.println("Number of records" + count);
    System.out.println("Maximum of  records" + max);
    System.out.println("Minimum of  records" + min);
    System.out.println("Sum of  records" + sum);
    System.out.println(" Average of  records" + avg);
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can use **SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;**